# How to correctly map one-to-many relationship using core data in Swift? Getting NSInvalidArgumentException error during attempts

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Here's my medicine object class and extension:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class Medicine: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var alarms: NSSet

}
```

-

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

extension Medicine {

@NSManaged var name: String?
@NSManaged var dosage: String?
@NSManaged var type: String?
@NSManaged var image: NSData?

func addAlarmObject(value:Alarm) {
    let items = self.mutableSetValueForKey("alarms") 
    items.addObject(value)
}

func removeDeleteObject(value:Alarm) {
    let items = self.mutableSetValueForKey("alarms")
    items.removeObject(value)
}

}
```

My alarm object:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

extension Alarm {

    @NSManaged var time: String?
    @NSManaged var weekdays: String?
    @NSManaged var isOwnedByMedicine: Medicine?

}
```

Screenshot of my data models and their relationship:

[image]

FINALLY, here is what I'm trying to do:

```
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name == %@", currentMedicine)
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Medicine")
        fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
        var fetchedCurrentMedicine:Medicine!
        do {
            let fetchedMedicines = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [Medicine]
            fetchedCurrentMedicine = fetchedMedicines.first
        } catch {

        }

        //add all the alarms to the Medicine class
        for alarmString in alarmList{
            let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Alarm", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
            let alarm = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext) as! Alarm
            alarm.setValue("test", forKey: "weekdays")
            alarm.setValue(String(alarmString), forKey: "time")
            fetchedCurrentMedicine.addAlarmObject(alarm)
        }
        do {
            try managedContext.save()
        } catch let error as NSError  {
            print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
```

It keeps failing at

```
fetchedCurrentMedicine.addAlarmObject(alarm)
```

and I get the error:

"'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'NSManagedObjects of entity 'Medicine' do not support -mutableSetValueForKey: for the property 'alarms''"

Any idea where I may have messed up or gotten the schema of my data models wrong? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your data model screen `alarms` relation of `Medicine` model is *to one*. Perhaps  `medicines` relation of `Alarm` model is *to-many*.
Anyway try to set *to-many* relation type for `alarms` in the data model inspector.

Comment: That did it. Thank you so much. I feel dumb because I didn't even realize you had to specify the relationship min/max that way. Thanks again.